# Change label of node in Jenkins after job is succeed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i was created a pipeline job that installs some things..
i want to do if the job is done with "success", so the label of the node will changed from "new" to "ready"...
someone can help to do this (with pipeline)?
this is my pipeline script:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'new-deployments'
    }
    stages {
        stage('main') {
            steps {
                sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                sh './deploy_script.sh'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            node('new-deployments') {
                // change the current node label to 'ready-deployments'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i was searching on google and stackoverflow, can't find something thats are really helps..

Comment: What is the use case for this? You update the node label from new-deployment to ready-deployment. Is it going to be the same everytime when the stage uses different nodes as each time the label is updated, 1 node from your build pool gets reduced for label new-deployment?

Comment: The new-deployment is a new nodes with nothing installed on them.. so if i run the job, it will install anything that i need, and change the label to "ready"..